# simultaneous equations word problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A stadium has two different types of seats, the lower section and the upper section.

- The lower section has 12 more rows than the upper section
- each row in the lower section has 40 seats
- each row in the upper section has 70 seats
- the stadium has a capacity of 6750 seats

By writing and solving a set of simultaneous equations, determine how many rows of seats there are in total in the stadium

Let x be the number of rows in the lower section
Let y be the number of rows in the upper section

Answer (score 1):

Well, with the last row in your question your almost done.

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{l}
x=y+12 \\ 
40x+70y=6750
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

Comment: so would I be right in saying that the answer is 96 rows?

Comment: No.  If you substitute $y + 12$ for $x$ in the second equation, you obtain $110y + 480 = 6750$. Solve for $y$, then substitute to obtain $x$.